# Julia-Studio:plot() not working even after adding Winston library

Tags: julia, julia-studio

I just installed Julia-Studio 0.4.4 on windows 7. And added the package Winston to try out plotting. So I did as below and got "FramedPlot(...)" output, no graphical figure.

```
using Winston
x=randn(1,1000);
plot(x)
FramedPlot(...)
```

What should I do to make it work? Any additional library?

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to call `display`, as in `plot(x) |> display`

Comment: @jverzani : Thank you, it worked. Please make your comment content to answer section. But when I was working in Linux with raw julia prompt, no 'display' command is required. That was the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same problem.  Looks like it was answered in the comments, but for future readers, you need to call `display()`:

```
using Winston
display( plot( randn(1,1000) ) )
```

Comment: I have the same problem and using `display()` still gives me a `FramedPlot(...)`. I run Julia on `Ubuntu 12.04` and on terminal.